# Elastic cloud multiple users

Tags: elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

We would like to move a bitnami vm  to the Elastic cloud offering on Azure.
We've created an instance in a resource group - And as the owner I can login and start managing this cluster.

Now I would like to invite other people to this cluster. We don't have the organization option in the Settings (elastic docs: Organizations are currently not supported for Azure Marketplace accounts.).

Therefore I added a user in "Stack Management > Security > Users", but that user can't login, can't reset a password, ...

Am I wrong by adding Users in the Stack Management, can we manage this in Azure AD?

Thanks!

Comment: We have the same problem, configured SSO based on their guide, but it only gives access to kibana, elastic API etc, but not to the deployment management (which is on cloud.elastic.co). If access to fewer features is enoug for you, maybe SSO will do.

Comment: Oh, and to login with SSO (I guess same applies to native users), you should not use the cloud login page, but your kibana URL which is something like  https://<your-deployment>.kb.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/

Comment: Currently we decided to use native users and as you suggested redirect them to https://<your-deployment>.kb.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/